# react-hook-form custom validation message not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form 6.8.2 with React 16.13.1 and normal validation works as expected, but not when inside of the "validate" key.

```
const { trigger, formState, watch, reset } = useFormContext({
    mode: 'all',
});
```

--

```
ref={register({
    required: 'This is required',
    minLength: {
        value: 3,
        message: 'Length must be 3 or more',
    },
    validate: {
        always: (value) => value === 1 || 'This should almost always trigger',
    },
    maxLength: {
        value: 5,
        message: 'max 5',
    },
})}
```

`required`, `minLength` and `maxLength` all work, but `always` doesn't.

I have tried this:
`always: (value) => value === 1 || console.log('This should almost always trigger')` which logs the error in the console

and I have tried this: `validate: (value) => value === 1 || 'This should almost always trigger'` which does nothing either

Why isn't the validation message shown in the UI?

Comment: Could you please provide a codesandbox with a minimal reproductible example and what should be the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there was a custom error rendering class, hidden deep within our own library for input fields, that didn't account for custom error types.

:(

Answer (score 2):

I made a CodeSandbox with your requirements using `react-hook-form@6.8.2` and `react@16.13.1` also using RHF's `useFormContext` hook. It's working fine, have a look:

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Custom Validation FormContext]

One thing that isn't correct in your example code: you're passing the `useForm` [config options](https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#useForm) to the `useFormContext` hook. That isn't working, you have to pass them instead to your `useForm` call. Check the CodeSandbox to see how to set the `mode` to 'all'.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Thanks to you, I found the real error which turned out to be a "helper"-class that someone made that explicitly checks for "normal" error types and does not account for custom ones, that's why it never rendered my error.

Comment: That's great, glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

In: **V7**

Instead of passing the `register` function's result to a ref, just call the register function with a spread operator on the input field. After this, you need a unique name for this input, just like for every input. In my example, your config works fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-js-forked-js0il?file=/src/App.js

Leave this answer for someone who looking for a similar solution.

Comment: You're using `react-hook-form` v7 and not v6

Comment: The answer above works, so I leave this for someone who looking for V7

Answer (score -1):

The validate function checks for your condition. If it returns false then the message can be displayed using the error mechanism like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const Example = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = values => console.log(values);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  
      <input
        {...register("username", {
          validate: value => value !== "admin" || "Nice try!"
        })}
      />
      {errors.username && errors.username.message} //Here we display the error

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't understand why your example is falsey and mine is truthy, they are both returning strings, are they not?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I am editing. The point is you have to use the errors object

Comment: I am using it, it works for all the normal validations. Or am I misunderstanding you?